# How to sort in an array between index specified

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I have an array/string/list (length = n) which needed to be sorted, not fully (i.e. not from 0 to (n-1)) but from an specified index ( k to (n-1)) to its end:

```
input_str = 'edayzadr'
sorted_str = 'edazyrda'
```

The sorting should only happen between index(3,7).

Comment: Your sorting doesn't make much sense. You sorted **in reverse** from indices 3 to 8, not 7.

Comment: Note that if you have a *string* or *tuple* (both immutable) rather than a *list* (mutable) the answer will be slightly different, so please clarify the title.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use slicing to apply the sort to the subsection, then re-join the parts:

```
return input_str[:3] + ''.join(sorted(input_str[3:7])) + input_str[7:]
```

Because `sorted()` on a string return individual characters, you need to re-join those.

You can apply the usual sorting arguments to `sorted()` like reversing. A helper function could make the handling of these and the start and end indices easier:

```
def sort_section(string, start, stop, **kwargs):
    mid = ''.join(sorted(string[start:stop], **kwargs))
    return string[:start] + mid + string[stop:]
```

Note that your sample is sorting from index 3 up to index **8** (Python slices are open ended, the end index is not included), and you *reversed* the sort:

```
>>> def sort_section(string, start, stop, **kwargs):
...     mid = ''.join(sorted(string[start:stop], **kwargs))
...     return string[:start] + mid + string[stop:]
... 
>>> sort_section('edayzadr', 3, 8, reverse=True)
'edazyrda'
```

For a tuple, you need to convert the `sorted()` output back to a tuple before concatenation:

```
input_tup[:3] + tuple(sorted(input_tup[3:7])) + input_tup[7:]
```

For a list object you can omit the `str.join()` call; you can just assign back to the same slice as a list at least is mutable:

```
sorted_lst[3:7] = sorted(input_lst[3:7])
```

Since you now have 3 different techniques for re-joining 3 string sections (my concatenation, and mhawke's `str.format` and `str.join` options), here is a quick benchmark as well to compare those:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> def concat(s):
...     return s[:3] + ''.join(sorted(s[3:7])) + s[7:]
... 
>>> def format(s):
...     return '{}{}{}'.format(s[:3], ''.join(sorted(s[3:7])), s[7:])
... 
>>> def join(s):
...     return ''.join((s[:3], ''.join(sorted(s[3:7])), s[7:]))
... 
>>> timeit("concat('edayzadr')", 'from __main__ import concat')
1.0208790302276611
>>> timeit("format('edayzadr')", 'from __main__ import format')
1.322662115097046
>>> timeit("join('edayzadr')", 'from __main__ import join')
1.1326570510864258
```

Comment: @rsm: I'm not so sure; there are just 2 concatenations; `str.format()` also takes time to parse the format, push the stack to call a method, and build a new string and pop the stack again. You'd have to time it, it is *not* a given that one or the other is faster.

Comment: @rsm: That may or may not be true. To be honest, the intent is probably clearer with `+` than `format()`.

Comment: @rsm: concatenation takes 1.0208790302276611, `str.format()` takes 1.322662115097046, and `str.join()` 1.1326570510864258 for 1 million iterations on sorting the `[3:7]` slice.

Comment: @rsm: repeated concatenation should be replaced by building a list and using `str.join()`, yes. But this is not repeated concatenation, this is a *small fixed number* of concatenations. At that scale other considerations are at play.

Comment: @rsm: if you want to; I've addressed it in the answer at any rate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use slicing to reference the substring that you wish to sort (using `sorted()`), and then reassemble the prefix, sorted substring, and suffix.

There are a few ways to do the reassembly, one is to use `str.format()`:

```
str = 'edayzadr'
sorted_str = '{}{}{}'.format(str[:3], ''.join(sorted(str[3:7])), str[7:])
```

Another way is to use `join()`:

```
sorted_str = ''.join((str[:3], ''.join(sorted(str[3:7])), str[7:]))
```